# Clear cookie via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cookies

I have a DNN installation but one of the portals is broken and the "logout" button doesnt seem to clear the cokoie. Is it possible to use jquery to clear a specific cookie? or a seperate ASP.NET page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, Using [cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) like this

```
$.cookie("name", null);
```

**Update:**

```
if($('a[href="webiste.co.uk\/en-gb\/admin.aspx"]').length) {
    $.cookie("name", null);
}
```

---

**Update 2:** Pure Js

```
function deleteCookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name+'="";-1; path=/';
}

var login = document.getElementById("loginlink");
login.onclick = function() {
  deleteCookie("name");
};
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't support this. You're using a jquery plugin.

Comment: is there a way to check if the page contains "<a href="http://www.webiste.co.uk/en-gb/admin.aspx">Admin</a>" then make the cookie null?

Comment: @Downvoter, There is another answer for your downvote above ;)

Comment: Totally :) The pure JS answer is the icing on the cake :-)

Comment: Up vote from me if you can put an on click event from a Login hyperlink.

Comment: @sp-1986, Bribing me are you? :)

Comment: @sp-1986, Yeah... swagatam ;)

Comment: i dont understand, is one a plugin version? and the other pure JS? which is better

Comment: @sp-1986, Better?? Big question?? One way to look at it is. If you are going to use Jquery for only this, No stop. Pure JS is the way to go.

Comment: Ill now tick this as completed/resolved.. Thank you.. would be good if you could make me a JSFIDDLE example?? not sure if thats possible with cookies. I would like to visualise this working before going live.

Comment: @sp-1986, It is possible, If you get stuck, I will create a demo then.

Comment: @Starx: are you up for a challenge: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102483/checking-a-cookie-exists-login-logoff-using-jquery-js