# checking a cookie exists Login Logoff using jquery / js

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, dotnetnuke, session-cookies

I have a DNN login/logoff control which isnt working properly. I want to therefore make my own using JS/JQUERY.

When the user is logged in the HTML on the page looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$dnnLOGIN$cmdLogin','')" class="SkinObject" id="dnn_dnnLOGIN_cmdLogin">Logout</a>
```

and when they are 'logged out' it looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$dnnLOGIN$cmdLogin','')" class="SkinObject" id="dnn_dnnLOGIN_cmdLogin">Login</a>
```

- I would like to check if the cookie has been set, if it has then
  display Logoff link and if it hasnt then display the Login link.
- Clicking on Login will check if the cookie exists (it should as Login
  was displayed) and take them to the login page.
- Clicking on Logoff should delete the cookie and the refresh the page
  which will then change the link back to 'Login' again because no cookie was found.

I was using this as an example guide: http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/73vzD/

This is what i have done so far:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="dnn_dnnLOGIN_cmdLogin" href="Login">
    Login
</a>

||

<a id="dnn_dnnLOGIN_cmdLogin" href="Logoff">
    Logoff
</a>

<br />

<a id="see" href="#">
    see
</a>
```

**JS:**

```
//set the cookie once user has logged in
//for testing purposes clicking login should set the cookie to 1
//clicking on Logoff 'should' set the cookie to 0
$('#dnn_dnnLOGIN_cmdLogin').live('click', function() {
    var action = $(this).attr('href');
    var cookie_value = (action == 'Login') ? 1 : null;

    $.cookie('DNN-COOKIE', cookie_value);

    return false;
});

// clicking on 'see' should bring up an alert box display the cookie value of 1 or 0
$('#see').live('click', function() {

    alert($.cookie('DNN-COOKIE'));

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I get "{"error": "Please use POST request"}" in jsfiddle which appears to be because it doesnt have a server to post to. The original example seems to work, my implementation doesnt.. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo of cookie is working just fine. Its seems you forgot to include the plugin.

See a working one [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/VSURE/)

---

**Update:**

You can check the preexisting of a cookie like this

```
var preval = $.cookie('cookie-name');
if(preval != null) {
    //... 
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/VSURE/1/)

Comment: Thank you.. Thats one problem out of the way. I need to do an IF statement to check if cookie exists then hide login link.

Comment: Thanks i have found the original problem and im not implementing the jquery. ps: have you ever been to base camp?

Comment: @sp-1986, No, unlucky till now. But next time you are at nepal, we are meeting for sure.

Comment: @sp-1986, What will trigger the hide action?

Comment: I am using $('#dnn_dnnLOGIN_cmdLogin').html('Login').css("visibility", "hidden"); then want to run the check on page load?

Comment: @sp-1986, No, I meant, which event will trigger the hiding process.

Comment: onClick event of #dnn_dnnLOGIN_cmdLogin

Comment: Thanks ill be able to use this code next time. Please dont delete it from your jsfiddle account. :)